# Decorators in different jars than implementation

Tags: java, decorator, cdi

I use Jboss 7.1.1 with Weld 1.1.10.

I have a war that includes two jars. In api.jar I have interfaces and in impl.jar I have implementations of the interfaces.

api.jar:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void myMethod();
}
```

impl.jar:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("This is my implementation");
    }
}
```

webapp.war:

```
public class MyRestApi {
    @Inject private MyInterface injected;

    @GET public Response doSomething() {
        injected.myMethod();
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Now I want include a decorator for MyInterface which I include in a third jar

decorator.jar:

```
@Decorator public class MyDecorator implements MyInterface {
    @Inject @Delegate @Any private MyInterface delegate;

    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("This is my decorator");
        delegate.myMethod();
    }
}
```

I would like to activate the decorator in beans.xml in the decorator.jar, but it seems that the only way to get the decorator to work is to activate it in impl.jar. This is not very practical since impl.jar does not know of decorator.jar. And what if I at a future point want to include more decorators, or have the same decorator apply to different implementations?

Given that I am limited to Jboss 7.1.1 atm, and upgrading to CDI 1.1 is not an option, how can I make the decorator work independent of the implementation?

Here is the beans.xml to activate the decorator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
    <decorators>
        <class>org.company.project.decorator.MyDecorator</class>
    </decorators>
</beans>
```

This is what I've found so far: If I put it in the war, in place of an empty one, the decorator is not activated. If I put it in decorator.jar, in place of an empty one, the decorator is not activated. If I put it in impl.jar, in place of an empty one, the decorator is activated.

Comment: `it seems that the only way to get the decorator to work is to activate it in impl.jar.` I doubt this is the only way, lets see what others have to say about possible solution.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56530647/cdi-decorating-a-service-from-another-jar

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the decorator in the war file's beans.xml.

Comment: Sorry this does not work. With decorator activated in war file's beans.xml, the output is: [stdout] (default task-1) This is my implementation

Comment: Please update your question to include the relevant beans.xml in the WAR, and each JAR file.  Also, is your REST API class annotated @Stateless or @RequestScoped?

Comment: Beans.xml added in the question. The REST API is irrelevant, it is only included to make a complete testable and deployable example. Why would scope, or being an EJB, make any difference on the behavior of the decorator?

Comment: It can make a lot of difference.  If it's not annotated anything, then the basic rules apply.  If it's annotated like a CDI bean more should happen.  So please include th einfo.

Comment: Testing on the server confirmed that neither scope nor EJB had any effect. Nor is this within the scope of the question.

Comment: Can you also say where your REST endpoint is included in this structure? The WAR's WEB-INF/classes, or if it's in a JAR which JAR?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation[1], seems not possible:

> The decorators that you specify in the beans.xml file apply only to
>   classes in the same archive.

So, you can put the class in a different Jar, but you cannot put the configuration esewhere.

[1]https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv007.htm