# CDI decorating a service from another JAR

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, decorator

I want to use CDI's Decorator pattern to augment business-logic provided by a service. The service that I attempt to decorate is located in another module (in maven terms), thus another JAR. For example, the provided service is in module `com.acme.provider` while the decorator is in `com.acme.consumer` next to the service consumer.

My service is being injected as-is, with no decoration.

The decorator is declared in the `beans.xml` inside the consumer module.

I provide a working example [here](https://github.com/ahmadshahwan/testciddecorators). Upon `mvn install`, test prints "Hello" and not "Hello World" as it would had decorator been applied.

If I move the decorator (and its xml declaration) to the providers module (see branch `decorator-in-provider` of same repository) things work fine and "Hello World" is printed.

If decorators only work when code of both provider bean and decorator itself is in the same module, I see little use of it. Is there such a limitation to Java EE decorator pattern? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 5):

OK, formalizing my question helped me find the answer.

As per [Oracle's tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv007.htm):

> The decorators that you specify in the beans.xml file apply only to
>   classes in the same archive. Use the @Priority annotation to specify
>   decorators globally for an application that consists of multiple
>   modules.

```
@Decorator
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION)
public abstract class CoderDecorator implements Coder { ... }
```

Branch `solution` in my working example repository solves the problem the right way.